# Ist "Kiez" Berliner Regionalsprache?

Tags: dialect, slang

Als ich in München studiert habe, bin ich dem Wort "Kiez" nicht einmal begegnet.

Aber jetzt in Berlin sehe ich das Wort überall: "im Kiez" ist die häufigste Verwendung, aber man sieht auch Dinge wie "pimp deinen Kiez" (das ist leider kein Witz).

Das Wörterbuch sagt, dass "Kiez" etwas derart wie "Stadt" oder "Viertel" bedeutet, aber ich habe den Eindruck, dass so eine Interpretation die ganze kulturelle Konnotation des Wortes nicht erfasst.

Ist "der Kiez" vielleicht ein Spitzname für Berlin, derart wie "the Big Apple" für New York City?

Sind meine Vermutungen richtig? Oder ist "Kiez" ein ganz normales Beispiel von Hochdeutsch, welches in Bayern vielleicht vernachlässigt wird?

Comment: Did you try to google it? There is a long English wikipedia article about Kiez: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiez

Comment: Den Artikel gibt es natürlich auch in Deutsch https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiez

Comment: @Iris I did not google it, although needless to say I should have. Should I delete the question then?

Comment: @Iris: Kannst du bitte in Wikipedia-Linkse in Zukunft das m rauslöschen? Also bitte »de.**m**.wikipedia.org« in »de.wikipedia.org« ändern. Die Version mit m ist für Handys optimiert (m = mobile), aber ich sitze vor einem 27"-Bildschirm, und auf diesem großen Schirm schaut die Handy-Version einfach nur beschissen aus, und ich bin sicher nicht der einzige. Handy-User werden beim Link ohne m ohnehin automatisch auf die Handy-Version umgeleitet, für die ist es egal.

Comment: @Hubert Schönast, ich versuche daran zu denken!

Comment: @William, das ist deine Entscheidung. Falls trotz Wikipediaartikel Fragen offen bleiben, kannst du die Frage auch editieren.

Comment: Da mach' ich gleich mal einen Vorschlag: Wie schreibt man's denn richtig? Wikipedia scheint sich nicht so recht zwischen *Kietz* und *Kiez* entscheiden zu können.

Comment: @tofro, das heutzutage verwendete 'Kiez' für Stadtviertel/Wohnviertel ist auf die früheren 'Kietze' (mittelalterlichen Dienstsiedlungen) zurück zu führen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich zitiere aus dem deutschen [Wikipediaartikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiez):

> Kiez bezeichnet vor allem in Berlin einen überschaubaren Wohnbereich
>   (beispielsweise einen Stadtteil), oft mit weitgehend vom Krieg
>   verschonten Gründerzeit-Gebäuden in „inselartiger“ Lage und einem
>   identitätsstiftenden Zugehörigkeitsgefühl in der Bevölkerung.
>
> In Hamburg steht die Bezeichnung für das Vergnügungsviertel im
>   Stadtteil St. Pauli um die Reeperbahn.
>
> Das Wort stammt von der Bezeichnung Kietz für mittelalterliche
>   Dienstsiedlungen im Nordosten Deutschlands. Die anfänglich meist
>   slawischen Bewohner waren für eine unmittelbar benachbarte Burg zu
>   Dienstleistungen verpflichtet (oft Abgabepflicht in Form von Fischen).

Der Artikel selbst ist noch viel länger und ist auch auf Englisch verfügbar.

Als Berliner würde ich nochmal hervorheben, dass "Kiez" für mich nicht mein offizielles Stadtviertel meint (das wäre zu groß). Sondern Kiez ist ein kleineren Bereich in der Stadt, wo sich mein Leben abspielt und wo ich mich gut auskenne. Also meine direkte Nachbarschaft und ein bisschen drumrum, wo ich z.B. mit meinem Kind auf den Spielplatz/in die Kirche/joggen/einkaufen/essen/auf den Markt/ Kaffee trinken gehen würde.

Comment: Die Frage ob regional oder nicht ist nicht gänzlich beleuchtet. Verwendet man das Wort in anderen Städten außer Berlin und Hamburg? Wird das Wort in ganz Norddeutschland verstanden, oder nur in den Städten?

Comment: @Beta,Wikipedia nennt Beispiele für Kieze in Berlin, Hamburg und Hannover. Allerdings ist Kiez in Hamburg Synonym mit dem Hamburger 'Rotlichtviertel'

Comment: Die Frage ist also nicht so einfach zu beantworten?

Comment: Ich denke, es wird in ganz Nordostdeutschland verstanden. Zumindest findet man auch für Dresden und Leipzig Treffer bei Google. Hamburg sehe ich eher als Ausnahme.

Answer (score -1):

Der Begriff "Kiez" hat erst durch den Zuzug hauptsächlich westdeutscher Einwanderer ab den 70er Jahren Verbreitung gefunden. Unter gebürtigen Berlinern war der Begriff weitgehend ungebräuchlich, verbreitete sich aber durch den häufigen medialen Gebrauch in den letzten Jahren zunehmend.

Comment: Hast Du eine Idee, wieso dann Wikipedia von Nordostdeutschland spricht, lt. Iris' Antwort?

Comment: "Westdeutsche" Einwanderer im geteilten Berlin der siebziger Jahre ist ja so oder so derbe unlogisch.